# Find avg time delay between user activity in SQL Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with three columns,

| userId | activity | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | post | 2022-05-18 |
| user2 | post | 2022-05-18 |
| user1 | post | 2022-05-17 |
| user3 | post | 2022-05-15 |
| user1 | post | 2022-05-13 |
| user1 | post | 2022-05-07 |

I want to find for all users, the avg number of days a particular user takes to do the activity (create post).
I tried doing a group by on userId and then find the avg of datediff but no success till now. Can some one please help me with this?

Here's the code I tried but didn't work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `newTable` as (
    select userId, 
    avg(DATE_DIFF(date, LAG(date) OVER (PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY date ASC), DAY)) AS avg_post_delay
    
    from `table2`
    where date between "2022-05-01" and "2022-05-31"
    group by userId
)
```

The expected output would look something like:

| userId | avgPostDelay |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | 3.66 |
| user2 | 5.1 |

Comment: Himanshu, do you have an id column for each row of `table2`?

Comment: how do you get 5.1 for user2, given the shared input? and what happened to user3?

Answer (score 1):

Your query seems to be almost close to the answer. Since an aggregate function `AGG()` is evaluated before a window function `LAG()`, what you need to do is to calculate the **datediff** first using a subquery and then calculate the average elapsed days for next post in your main query.

```sql
SELECT userId, ROUND(AVG(datediff), 2) AS avg_diff 
  FROM (
    SELECT userId,
           DATE_DIFF(date, LAG(date) OVER (PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY date), DAY) datediff
      FROM `table2`
  )
 GROUP BY 1;
```

I've slightly modified your sample table.

```sql
DECLARE sample ARRAY<STRUCT<userId STRING, activity STRING, date DATE>> DEFAULT [
    ('user1', 'post', DATE '2022-05-18'),
    ('user2', 'post', '2022-05-18'),
    ('user1', 'post', '2022-05-17'),
    ('user2', 'post', '2022-05-15'),
    ('user1', 'post', '2022-05-13'),
    ('user1', 'post', '2022-05-07')
];
CREATE TEMP TABLE table2 AS SELECT * FROM UNNEST(sample);
```

output:

[image]